# Cross-referenced double foreign key constraint

Tags: database, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a table of light **fixture_models**:

```
id  | name
--- | -----------
1   | Wall sconce
2   | Ceiling fan
```

Another table lists the sockets that a fixture model has, called **fixture_model_sockets**:

```
id  | fixture_model_id | socket_type
--- | ---------------- | -----------
1   | 1                | GU-24
2   | 2                | E26
3   | 2                | E26
4   | 2                | E26
```

The wall sconce has one GU-24 socket, and the ceiling fan has three E26 sockets. This table has a foreign key constraint on fixture_model_id.

And there's a table of **fixtures**:

```
id  | fixture_model_id | location
--- | ---------------- | ----------
1   | 1                | East Wall
2   | 1                | West Wall
3   | 2                | Ceiling
```

There are two wall sconces, one each on the east and west wall, and there is one ceiling fan. This table also has a foreign key constraint on fixture_model_id.

When installing a light bulb, it should be recorded in the **bulbs** table:

```
id  | fixture_id | fixture_model_socket_id | type | power
--- | ---------- | ----------------------- | ---- | -----
1   | 1          | 1                       | Inc. | 75
2   | 2          | 1                       | Inc. | 75
3   | 3          | 2                       | LED  | 13
4   | 3          | 3                       | LED  | 13
5   | 3          | 4                       | LED  | 13
```

This table has two foreign key constraints, one on fixture_id and on on fixture_model_socket_id table. In addition, to enforce the fact that only one bulb can be installed in any one socket at a time, it has a uniqueness constraint on fixture_id and fixture_model_socket_id.

My question: How do I enforce the fact that a bulb can only be installed in a socket associated with the fixture's model? That is, it would be invalid for a bulb to have fixture_id = 1 (which belongs to the wall sconce) and fixture_model_socket_id = 2 (which belongs to the ceiling fan). Is this an issue with my schema, or just something that should be enforced at the application level?

Comment: This is a faq. Google your title & your "My question" with 'stackoverflow database'.

Comment: @philipxy I had already tried your suggestion before asking this question, and it returned many answers about compound keys, polymorphic keys, and keys in different databases, but none that apply. If this is a frequently asked question then it would have been easier for you to provide an example link than to tell me to google it.

Comment: It's still a faq. Since you now know that, you can google some more. I get tired of it. It is clear that people do a poor job of it. Look at my comments on the FK tags. You are the 4th in 4 days. Notice I didn't downvote this or vote to close. Probably there's another one like your case that I left a faq comment on within the last week.

Comment: @philipxy Please either provide a link to a duplicate question or refrain from commenting here.